# Re-rendering behaviour and referential equality in React

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I'm encountering a re-rendering behaviour in my React app that is making me think I don't really understand React re-renders.

I'm using Apollo and polling some messages on my backend. I want to update a state array of messages if there are any new ones, and then de-dupe the array. Finally, I want to memoize this so that the consumers of my messages array aren't constantly getting re-rendered. This is what I have:

```
const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Message[]>([])
const formerRef = useRef<Message[]>([])

useQuery(MESSAGES_QUERY, {
    variables: { gameId },
    pollInterval: 500,
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      setCursor(data.messagesByGame.cursor)
      setMessages((prev) => [...prev, ...data.messagesByGame.messages])
    },
  })

const memoized = useMemo(() => {
    const returnedMessages = []
    messages.forEach((message) => {
      if (!returnedMessages.find((m) => m.id === message.id)) {
        returnedMessages.push(message)
      }
    })
    return returnedMessages
  }, [messages])

  if (memoized !== formerRef.current) {
    console.log('not the same', memoized)
  } else {
    console.log('is the same', memoized)
  }
  formerRef.current = memoized
```

It seems that memoizing is not working here. Even though I'm creating a new array in `setMessages`, the returnedMessages value should be memoized. Messages in this case looks like an array of objects.

It would be great if someone could point out where I'm going wrong...

EDIT I'm starting to think that my problem is that an array of objects isn't memoizable, because the objects will always have different references. In which case I might need to rethink my whole approach, or rely on library code...

Comment: You send a request off every 500ms, so every 500ms on the response you concat the result of that to all previous results - this is a new array every time that is X results longer than the last one. What exactly do you think memoization will do for you here?

Comment: He's reinitializing the array every time… see `const returnedMessages = []`

Answer (score 0):

You've got an extra state variable `messages` in there that may be unnecessary.

When memoizing I usually just use the `data` variable coming out of the query to decide when to update the filtered array.

Ex:

```
const { data, loading, error} = useQuery(MESSAGES_QUERY, {
    variables: { gameId },
    pollInterval: 500,
);

const memoized = useMemo(() => data?.messagesByGame?.messages.filter(
    (m,i) => data.messagesByGame.messages.find(m) === i
  ), [data?.messagesByGame])
```

Comment: thanks Michel, will see if this helps